# Народ подскажите пожалуйста как собрать rust github проект оффлайн?

Tags: rust, build, offline

Есть rust проект на github необходимо его собрать на оффлайн машине i386 Все необходимые crate- зависимости для него уже скачаны, к сожалению в сети не нашел пошаговых инструкций для этого?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65254702/4777440